# How the CAN identifiers are formed?

Tags: can-bus

I'm new to CAN, So i would like to know how the **CAN Identifiers** or    **Message Identifiers** are defined and those bits in those **ID** represents?

Comment: If you are in your own network, then you can define your own Message ID catalog... If you want to follow certain standards, then refer it's message ID catalog

Comment: Thank You @Swanand. Can you help to find out the difference between Normal Addressing, Normal Fixed Addressing, Extended Addressing and Mixed Addressing. How and When we use **(Scenario)**?